# Unable to find master in Jenkins for GIT

Tags: git, jenkins

please find the output of the Jenkins, where its not able to find the master in GIT.

DEBUG [9bfc5130] Running /usr/bin/env git rev-list --max-count=1 --abbrev-commit --abbrev=12 master as jenkins@localhost
 DEBUG [9bfc5130] Command: ( export GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/sporttu-dash/git-ssh.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git rev-list --max-count=1 --abbrev-commit --abbrev=12 master )
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Command::Failed: git exit status: 32768
git stdout: Nothing written
**git stderr: fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.**
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git  [...] -- [...]'

Tasks: TOP => gitcopy:create_release => gitcopy:create_tarfile => gitcopy:set_current_revision
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: git exit status: 32768
git stdout: Nothing written
**git stderr: fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.**
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git  [...] -- [...]'
 DEBUG [9bfc5130]   fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
 DEBUG [9bfc5130]   Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
 DEBUG [9bfc5130]   'git  [...] -- [...]'
+ RETVAL=1
+ kill 30823
Finished: SUCCESS

please guide.

thanks
Victor

Comment: Does your repo have a branch named 'master'? If not, use the branch name that exists. Is there a file named 'master' as well as a branch named master? If yes, be careful when running commands like `git checkout master`. `git checkout master --` to checkout the branch master. `git checkout -- master` to checkout the file master of the work tree.

Comment: please find the output
[root@s195-qa-bastion-1 sporttu-console-qa]# git checkout -- master

pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Comment: could you list the output of `git ls-remote | grep master`?

Comment: I ran as jenkins

bash-4.2$ cd /media/jenkins/workspace/sporttu-console-qa/

bash-4.2$ git ls-remote | grep master

From git@github.com:sport195/sporttu-dash.git

5e5391cd7f7749ab1f87b1cdf07d692288ac85c2        refs/heads/master

bash-4.2$

Comment: so the branch named 'master' does exist in the remote repo. How about `git branch | grep master`?

Comment: no output
bash-4.2$ git branch | grep master
bash-4.2$

Comment: so there is no branch named master in the local repo. You could run `git fetch origin master && git branch master FETCH_HEAD` to create a branch named master.

Comment: Please find the output, still the same error

bash-4.2$ git fetch origin master && git branch master FETCH_HEAD
remote: Counting objects: 1484, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (66/66), done.
remote: Total 1484 (delta 375), reused 349 (delta 349), pack-reused 1067
Receiving objects: 100% (1484/1484), 306.87 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (913/913), completed with 114 local objects.
From github.com:sport195/sporttu-dash
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
   2c8df9e..5e5391c  master     -> origin/master
bash-4.2$
bash-4.2$
bash-4.2$

Comment: bash-4.2$ /usr/bin/env git rev-list --max-count=1 --abbrev-commit --abbrev=12 master as jenkins@localhost
fatal: ambiguous argument 'as': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
bash-4.2$

Comment: what does `git branch -a` show? Is there an exact  'master'?

Comment: may be it works, let me update you in a while,

Comment: bash-4.2$ git branch -a
* (HEAD detached at 2c8df9e)
  master
  remotes/origin/bootstrap
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/release
  remotes/origin/sprint-4

Comment: yes, we can see master now, I am running the jenkin job now

bash-4.2$ git branch | grep master
  master
bash-4.2$

Comment: It's in detached HEAD state. Maybe you could simply modify the `master` in `git rev-list` to `HEAD` in your case, since `git fetch origin master` always gets the latest commit which may not be what you want.

Comment: I ran the job and below is the output.

 INFO [1a27db65] Finished in 22.306 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
+ RETVAL=0
+ kill 3076
Finished: SUCCESS

Let me get confirmation from developers, thank you so much for helping me out.

I will update the results shortly.